# as.numeric() producing NAs for what should be numbers

Tags: r, web-scraping, character-encoding, na, gsub

I am scraping the Illinois department of corrections website (https://www2.illinois.gov/idoc/facilities/Pages/Covid19Response.aspx) and trying to create a vector called Staff.Confirmed for the number of staff who have contracted COVID-19. I run the following code

```
    url <- "https://www2.illinois.gov/idoc/facilities/Pages/Covid19Response.aspx"
    web <- read_html(url)
    Staff.Confirmed.html <- html_nodes(web,'.soi-rteTableOddCol-1:nth-child(2)')
    Staff.Confirmed <- html_text(Staff.Confirmed.html)
    Staff.Confirmed <- as.numeric(Staff.Confirmed)
```

which produces the following output when I call Staff.Confirmed:

```
[1] "​1"  "​1"  "​1"  "​4"  "​5"  "​7"  "​1"  "​1"  "​2"  "​1"  "​13" "​3"  "​4"  "​2"  "​4"  "​2"  "​0"  "​8"  "​8"  "​1"  "​79" "​37" "​0"  "​1"  "​1"
```

However, when I run

```
Staff.Confirmed <- as.numeric(Staff.Confirmed)
```

I get the warning message "NAs introduced by coercion." Every number has become an NA. As far as I can tell, there are no whitespaces, nor any other issues which should be causing this. Has anyone else encountered this issue before?

I tried running

```
Staff.Confirmed <- gsub(pattern="^[0-9]",replacement="",Staff.Confirmed)
Staff.Confirmed <- as.numeric(Staff.Confirmed)
```

But the same error occurred. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Your `gsub()` pattern was very close, btw. You just needed to put the carrot `^` inside the brackets to remove everything that was not a digit.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew! That did fix the issue as well. I appreciate the help! My mistake with the gsub code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a unicode letter (<U+200B> = zero width space) hiding at the first position of each string. Remove it and it works:

```
url <- "https://www2.illinois.gov/idoc/facilities/Pages/Covid19Response.aspx"
web <- read_html(url)
Staff.Confirmed.html <- html_nodes(web,'.soi-rteTableOddCol-1:nth-child(2)')
Staff.Confirmed <- substr(html_text(Staff.Confirmed.html), 2, 999)
Staff.Confirmed <- as.numeric(Staff.Confirmed)
```

It was very easy to spot in the "environment pane" of RStudio. The pane displayed the vector like this:

```
chr [1:25] "<U+200B>1" "<U+200B>1" "<U+200B>1" "<U+200B>4" ...
```

and I was able to confirm it with `nchar(html_text(Staff.Confirmed.html))` that each string was too long by exactly 1 character.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked perfectly. I really appreciate your help! Out of curiosity, how did you identify the unicode? In case anyone else comes across this issue, it would be nice for them to know how to do it. No worries if you don't have time to get into it though. I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: you can see them when you enter `str(Staff.Confirmed)`

Comment: Thank you both @Jan and @Tom for the help! I tried doing it for the next column (Staff.Recovered), but for some reason both my environment pane in RStudio and running `str(Staff.Recovered)` just show `chr [1:25] "​1" "​1" "​1" "​2" "​5" "​7" "​1" "​1" "​2" "​1" "​7" "​2" "​4" "​2" "​4" "​2" "​0" "​6" "​8" "​1" "​76" "​32" "​0" "​0" "​1"`
Is there a view option I'm somehow missing? The fix for Staff.Confirmed unfortunately doesn't seem to work for Staff.Recovered (or Residents.Confirmed or Residents.Recovered) so I just want to make sure I'm able to see the unicode. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I cannot replicate it. I see the same issue in the next column, too. When I look at the site with the developer panel, when I use RStudio, and with `str(Staff.Recovered)`. I get `chr [1:25] "<U+200B>1" "<U+200B>1" "<U...`again.

Comment: @Jan thanks for the help. It seems to be in everything from the website unfortunately (same with the facility names). I can remove it from Staff.Confirmed, Residents.Confirmed, and Staff.Recovered. Unfortunately, the gsub nor the substr() command you helpfully gave me works for Residents.Recovered or Name (the facility names). I might just have to copy that part down by hand every day I guess. I really appreciate your help thus far!

Comment: So this is not a good solution, but I did manage to remove the unicode by using `Residents.Recovered <- sub('.','',Residents.Recovered)` to remove the first character in each string. This of course won't work when the unicode is hidden somewhere other than the first character, so a longer-term solution could be helpful, but the immediate need seems to have been met. I appreciate the help greatly!

Answer (score 1):

New idea. Two principles:

1. This approach does not look for invalid characters. It looks for everything we want to keep and discards the rest.
2. We get the table in one large gulp instead of column by column

```
    # Fetch the data
    url <- "https://www2.illinois.gov/idoc/facilities/Pages/Covid19Response.aspx"
    web <- read_html(url)
    
    # extract table and keep only valid characters
    raw <- as.character(html_node(web, ".soi-rteTable-1")) # get table and coerce it to character
    nchar(raw) # see how long it is
    raw <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]|[:space:]|[:punct:]]", "", raw) # keep only valid characters
    nchar(raw) # length got reduced
    df <- html_table(minimal_html(raw), header = TRUE, trim = TRUE)
    df <- df[[1]] # html_table returns a list, so get the first element

    # check if columns are numeric
    str(df)
    'data.frame':   26 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ Locations                         : chr  "Crossroads ATC" "Danville" "Dixon" "East Moline" ...
     $ Staff Confirmed                   : int  1 1 1 4 5 7 1 1 2 1 ...
     $ Staff Recovered                   : int  1 1 1 2 5 7 1 1 2 1 ...
     $ Incarcerated Individuals Confirmed: int  3 0 0 28 0 4 0 0 15 0 ...
     $ Incarcerated Individuals Recovered: int  3 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 15 0 ...
```

Voilà! On character column with labels and 4 integer columns.